# In durandaljs my nav a tags are not loading my routes

Tags: durandal

I just upgraded my project to durandaljs 2.0.
Everything seems to be working fine in the sense that if I enter a route url in the browser address bar and hit enter it loads the view for the hash route perfectly fine.  This works for all of my routes.

But if I click on the navbar button that has the exact same hash routes in the href, the browser url changes to the correct url (the one that works if I hit enter in the address bar) but the view doesn't load.

It's almost like a router.navigate without a trigger is getting called.

I actually manually tried calling route.navigate("#xyz", { replace: false, trigger: true }) but that doesn't load the xyz view either.

I am overlooking something silly here - any ideas?

from shell.js:

```
activate: function () {
    $.getJSON("/Account/GetCurrentUser").done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        shell.user(data);
    });


    $(document).ajaxError(function (xhr, props) {
        if (props.status === 401) {
            window.location = "/Account/Login";
        }
    });

    router.map([
        { route: '', title: 'Jobs', moduleId: 'viewmodels/jobs', nav: true },
        { route: 'companies', title: 'Companies', moduleId: 'viewmodels/companies', nav: true },
        { route: 'profile', title: 'Profile', moduleId: 'viewmodels/profile', nav: true },
        { route: 'users', title: 'Users', moduleId: 'viewmodels/users', nav: true, hash: '#users' },
        { route: 'jobs(/filter/:filter)(/group/:group)(/sort/:sort)(/page/:page)', title: 'Jobs', moduleId: 'viewmodels/jobs', nav: false },
        { route: 'companies(/filter/:filter)(/group/:group)(/sort/:sort)(/page/:page)', title: 'Companies', moduleId: 'viewmodels/companies', nav: false }

        //,{ route: 'flickr', moduleId: 'viewmodels/flickr', nav: true }
    ]).buildNavigationModel();

    //router.mapNav('details');
    //router.mapNav('airports');
    //router.mapNav('emptylegs');

    return router.activate();
}
```

from nav.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="max-height:68px">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="/">
            <span class="title"></span>
        </a>        
        <div>
            <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.navigationModel">
                <li><a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: title"
                    class="btn btn-info" href="#"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the html with the links and the router configuration? Thank you!

Comment: Ok - just added activate from shell.js and the html from nav.html to the post.

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered HTML via a browser debugger?  What's the `href` attribute render as?

Comment: this is how one of them renders but the view doesn't load whe clicked: <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: title" class="btn btn-info" href="#users">Users</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that's the problem, but in the `a` binding you are changing href with knockout and  then setting `href="#"` again.

```
<a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: title"
                class="btn btn-info" href="#"></a>
```

Might not be the cause of the problem. But this doesn't look good..

By the way, also check that the binding with the router is properly done. In Durandal 2.0 it changed, so in your `shell.html` you should have something like this:

```
<!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
```

Instead of this:

```
<!--ko compose: {
    model: router.activeItem, 
    afterCompose: router.afterCompose, 
    transition: 'entrance'
} -->
```

Comment: Many thanks margabit!  It was the shell.html router binding syntax that was causing the problem...

Comment: No problem @t316! Enjoy Durandal!